# Size classes on Modal Views

Tags: iphone, ipad, modalviewcontroller, size-classes, adaptive-layout

I am trying to set different constraints for iPad and iPhone (4'').

I have set Regular Height and Compact width constraints for iPhone. But these constraints are shown on 7.9'' iPad, 9.7'' iPad.

These constraints are for a modal view.

How do i make my Regular Height and Compact width constraints limit to my iPhones only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the form sheet presentation on iPad is compact width and regular height, It is taking those constraints.

[Formsheet ios 8 constraints are same as iphones constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162615/formsheet-ios-8-constraints-are-same-as-iphones-constraints)

The solution is to override traitCollection in the Presented view controller

```
override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection
{
    if UIDevice.isIPad()
    {
        let traits = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular)
        let traits2 = UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular)
        let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: [traits, traits2])

        return traitCollection
    }
    else
    {
        return super.traitCollection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a note, iOS Docs have this warning for `traitCollection`:

> Use the traitCollection property directly. Do not override it. Do not provide a custom implementation.

With that known, here's an Obj-C solution which combines `super` traits w/ updated horizontal/vertical traits:

```
- (UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    UITraitCollection *traitCollection = [super traitCollection];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UITraitCollection *horizontalTraitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
        UITraitCollection *verticalTraitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithVerticalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
        traitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:@[traitCollection, horizontalTraitCollection, verticalTraitCollection]];
    }
    return traitCollection;
}
```