# override UITraitCollection of a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitraitcollection

I have a `UITabBar` which has to have a traitCollection with compact horizontalSizeClass.
Because on a regular horizontalSizeClass, `UITabBar` renders TabBarIcon and Title side by side.

I did subclass `UITabBar` and overriden the traitCollection getter to give me modified traitCollection.

```
override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection{
    let current = super.traitCollection
    let compact = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)
    return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [current, compact])
}
```

This does the job but, I started getting below warning

> Class MyTabBar overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.

After checking Apple Documentation I did find one API, [overrideTraitCollection(forChild:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621486-overridetraitcollection)
But the viewController which holds my UITabBar needs to have regular horizontalSizeClass.

I also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483414/how-to-override-trait-collection-for-initial-uiviewcontroller-with-storyboard) but it doesn't answer my question of overriding the traitCollection of a `UIView`.

I don't want to override the traitCollection of a `UIViewController` but only the `UIView`.

What is the right way to override traitCollection of a `UIView`?